# JS - Editing a child object of an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops

Here's the data (set to the state name of *comments*)

```
    [
{
    "id": 1,
    "content": "Impressive! Though it seems the drag feature could be improved. But overall it looks incredible. You've nailed the design and the responsiveness at various breakpoints works really well.",
    "createdAt": "1 month ago",
    "score": 12,
    "user": {
        "image": {
            "png": "./images/avatars/image-amyrobson.png",
            "webp": "./images/avatars/image-amyrobson.webp"
        },
        "username": "amyrobson"
    },
    "replies": []
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "content": "Woah, your project looks awesome! How long have you been coding for? I'm still new, but think I want to dive into React as well soon. Perhaps you can give me an insight on where I can learn React? Thanks!",
    "createdAt": "2 weeks ago",
    "score": 5,
    "user": {
        "image": {
            "png": "./images/avatars/image-maxblagun.png",
            "webp": "./images/avatars/image-maxblagun.webp"
        },
        "username": "maxblagun"
    },
    "replies": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "content": "If you're still new, I'd recommend focusing on the fundamentals of HTML, CSS, and JS before considering React. It's very tempting to jump ahead but lay a solid foundation first.",
            "createdAt": "1 week ago",
            "score": 4,
            "replyingTo": "maxblagun",
            "user": {
                "image": {
                    "png": "./images/avatars/image-ramsesmiron.png",
                    "webp": "./images/avatars/image-ramsesmiron.webp"
                },
                "username": "ramsesmiron"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "content": "I couldn't agree more with this. Everything moves so fast and it always seems like everyone knows the newest library/framework. But the fundamentals are what stay constant.",
            "createdAt": "2 days ago",
            "score": 2,
            "replyingTo": "ramsesmiron",
            "user": {
                "image": {
                    "png": "./images/avatars/image-juliusomo.png",
                    "webp": "./images/avatars/image-juliusomo.webp"
                },
                "username": "juliusomo"
            }
        }
    ]
}]
```

This code successfully deletes the correct comment clicked on, even if it's a child comment of a parent comment

```
  const { comments, setLoading } = useContext(CommentsContext);

function handleDelete(e) {
    setLoading(true);

    function deleteComment(id, arr) {
        arr.forEach(function (item, index) {
            if (item.id == id) {
                arr.splice(index, 1);
            } else if (item.replies && item.replies.length > 0) {
                deleteComment(id, item.replies);
            }
        });
    }

    deleteComment(e.target.id, comments);

    setTimeout(() => {
        setLoading(false);
    }, 100);
}
```

So I copied it and have been trying to rework it to allow me to edit the comment that's clicked on

```
 function handleEdit(e) {
    setLoading(true);

    function editComment(id, arr) {
        arr.forEach(function (item, index) {
            if (item.id == id) {
                console.log("first layer");
            } else if (item.replies && item.replies.length > 0) {
                console.log("second layer");
            }
        });
    }

    editComment(e.target.id, comments);

    setTimeout(() => {
        setLoading(false);
    }, 100);
```

From here I can generate the console log of "second layer" when clicking on a child comment but it's pulling the information from the parent comment. I.e. I'm clicking the child comment with the id of 4 but it's giving me the info of it's parent comment with the id of 2.

I tried running a loop and for each within the else if but it just didn't work at all.

The idea is to click the edit button, it changes the comment's content to a textarea with the previous content autofilling the input, changing something, and having that save over the comments state.

EDIT:

The following worked:

```
  function handleEdit(e) {
    setLoading(true);

    function editComment(id, arr) {
        arr.forEach(function (item, index) {
            if (item.id == id) {
                console.log("open textarea for item: " + id);
            } else if (item.replies && item.replies.length > 0) {
                for (let i = 0; i < item.replies.length; i++) {
                    if (item.replies[i].id == id) {
                       
                        item.replies[i].content = (
                            <textarea
                                className="w-full h-[100px] bg-secondary border rounded p-3 outline-none"
                                placeholder="Edit a comment..."
                            />
                        );
                        editComment(item.id, item.replies);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't copy the logic well. You haven't provided an example but it makes sense to copy it like this:

```js
function handleEdit(e) {
  setLoading(true);

  function editComment(id, arr) {
    arr.forEach(function(item, index) {
      if (item.id == id) {
        console.log("open textarea for item: " + id)
      } else if (item.replies && item.replies.length > 0) {
        editComment(item.id, item.replies);

      }
    });
  }

  editComment(e.target.id, comments);

  setTimeout(() => {
    setLoading(false);
  }, 100);
}
```

Comment: "editComment(id, comments);"  generates a rangeerror. "editComment(id, item.replies);" just pulls the data from the parent comment.

Comment: i fixed it, twice. please have a try again.

Comment: item.id brings up the id for the parent comment (id = 2) and item.replies brings up an array with child comments 1 (id = 3) and 2 (id = 4). I tried to go a bit deeper with item.replies.id but that gives me the error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')". I can loop through the replies with "for (let i = 0; i < item.replies.length; i++)" and console log out each reply individually. With an if statement " if (item.replies[i].id == id) {editComment(item.id, item.replies);}" it should work but it's not activing the console log of "open textarea for item"

Comment: Editing the main post with what worked